# iOS - Preloading a Page View Controller and its child view controllers

Tags: ios, objective-c

When my app's tab view loads, I am trying to also load a page view Controller and hold it in memory for the life of the app. The page View is my self.playerQueueViewController.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{
   [super viewDidLoad];
 self.playerQueueViewController = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MusicPlayerQueue" bundle:nil] instantiateInitialViewController];
    self.playerQueueViewController.transitioningDelegate = self;
    self.playerQueueViewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCustom;
}
```

Now, the view will only load when I call,

```
-(void)centerButtonPressed:(id)sender
{
    [self presentViewController:self.playerQueueViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

How would I get the view to load and load the page view controller's child view controllers as soon as my tabViewController loads? I am trying to hold all of these view controllers in memory.

Here is how I have set up my pageViewController.

What is currently happening is that the pageViewController get's loaded only when I present it modally with -(void)centerButtonPressed. And the child views get loaded when I call -(void)goToPrevious, -(void)goToNext

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) SAMusicPlayerViewController *playerViewController;
@property (strong, nonatomic) SAQueueViewController *queueViewController;
@end

@implementation SAPageRootViewController

- (IBAction)dissmissArrowPressed:(UIButton *)sender
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

#pragma mark - Setters and Getters

- (NSArray *)contentPageRestorationIDs
{
    if (!_contentPageRestorationIDs) {
        _contentPageRestorationIDs = @[@"Player", @"Queue",];
    }

    return _contentPageRestorationIDs;
}


- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Create the page view controller.
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MusicPlayerQueue" bundle:nil];
    self.pageViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PageViewController"];
    self.queueViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Queue"];
    self.queueViewController.rootViewController = self;
    self.playerViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Player"];
    self.playerViewController.rootViewController = self;

    NSLog(@"Page Root Load");

    // Instantiate the first view controller.

    [self.pageViewController setViewControllers:@[self.playerViewController]
                                      direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward
                                       animated:NO
                                     completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                                         // Completion code
                                     }];

    // Add the page view controller to this root view controller.
    [self addChildViewController:self.pageViewController];
    [self.view addSubview:self.pageViewController.view];
    [self.pageViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];

    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:self.dismissArrowButton];

}

#pragma mark - Public Methods
- (void)goToPreviousContentViewController
{
    // Get index of current view controller
    SAQueueViewController *currentViewController = self.queueViewController;
    currentViewController.currentButton.enabled = NO;

    UIViewController *previousViewController = self.playerViewController;


    [self.pageViewController setViewControllers:@[previousViewController]
                                      direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionReverse
                                       animated:YES
                                     completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                                         currentViewController.currentButton.enabled = YES;
                                     }];
}

- (void)goToNextContentViewController
{
    // Get index of current view controller
    SAMusicPlayerViewController *currentViewController = self.playerViewController;
    currentViewController.queueButton.enabled = NO;

    UIViewController *nextViewController = self.queueViewController;

    [self.pageViewController setViewControllers:@[nextViewController]
                                      direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward
                                       animated:YES
                                     completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                                         currentViewController.queueButton.enabled = YES;
                                     }];
}
```

UPDATE:

I am now able to load the page view and the initial child view for the pageViewController like this. The problem is that I am not able to load the second child view controller on initial load.

All of this code is in my tabViewController's viewDidLoad

```
self.pageRootViewController = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MusicPlayerQueue" bundle:nil] instantiateInitialViewController];
self.pageRootViewController.transitioningDelegate = self;
self.pageRootViewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCustom;


UIPageViewController *pageViewController = self.pageRootViewController.pageViewController;
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MusicPlayerQueue" bundle:nil];
pageViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PageViewController"];
self.queueViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Queue"];
self.queueViewController.rootViewController = self.pageRootViewController;
self.playerViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Player"];
self.playerViewController.rootViewController = self.pageRootViewController;

// Add the page view controller to this root view controller.
[self.pageRootViewController addChildViewController:pageViewController];
[self.pageRootViewController.view addSubview:pageViewController.view];
[pageViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self.pageRootViewController];
[self.pageRootViewController.view bringSubviewToFront:self.pageRootViewController.dismissArrowButton];

// Instantiate the first view controller.

[pageViewController setViewControllers:@[self.playerViewController, self.queueViewController]
                            direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionReverse
                                   animated:NO
                                 completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                                     // Completion code
                                 }];
```

UPDATE 2:

Okay I have my code working exactly how I want it to. However, I'm not sure if this is the best way to go about fixing this problem. It seems alright. The only thing I don't like is calling `[self.queueViewController view]`

In tabBarController's viewDidLoad

```
   self.pageRootViewController = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MusicPlayerQueue" bundle:nil] instantiateInitialViewController];
    self.pageRootViewController.transitioningDelegate = self;
    self.pageRootViewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCustom;


    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MusicPlayerQueue" bundle:nil];
    UIPageViewController *pageViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PageViewController"];
    self.pageRootViewController.pageViewController = pageViewController;
    self.queueViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Queue"];
    self.queueViewController.rootViewController = self.pageRootViewController;
    [self.queueViewController view];
    self.playerViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Player"];
    self.playerViewController.rootViewController = self.pageRootViewController;

    self.pageRootViewController.queueViewController = self.queueViewController;
    self.pageRootViewController.playerViewController = self.playerViewController;

    // Add the page view controller to this root view controller.
    [self.pageRootViewController addChildViewController:pageViewController];
    [self.pageRootViewController.view addSubview:pageViewController.view];
    [pageViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self.pageRootViewController];
    [self.pageRootViewController.view bringSubviewToFront:self.pageRootViewController.dismissArrowButton];

    // Instantiate the first view controller.

    [pageViewController setViewControllers:@[self.playerViewController]
                                direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionReverse
                                       animated:NO
                                     completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                                         // Completion code
                                     }];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really have to preload it, call .view on the ViewController, which will force the load.

It shouldnt be neccessary to preload the view. You could animate the loading of the subviews to enhance the UX and keep the performance.

Comment: I need to add observers to a notification center when my tabViewController loads

Comment: This extends into a larger architecture decision, but it seems like you would be better off moving the observers and data fetching into another object. This object can be passed around as needed. ViewController's should be lightweight. It is bad design to need to load up the entire apps object graph, setting up observers on views that arent visible etc. As you can see its causing strange dependencies and hacks that just make it more difficult to extend your project. If you use web services, centralise it, allow access to it through a clean interface that the view controllers can use.

Comment: Okay. How should I move the observers into another object. Could you possibly provide an example? Thanks

Comment: What are you trying to observe, why exactly do you need it preloaded?

Comment: I am observing for when the user adds a song/track to a queue, the notification then tells the table View to reload. 

But what you are suggesting is that I have a global queue? and add the data when the view loads each time?

Comment: Ok, thats makes more sense. You should build your queue independently of the VC. E.g. create a NSObject for the players preferences etc. You could store the queue in there. This NSObject could then be passed around to whatever VC needs it, or made a singleton (Its not a bad pattern unless its abused, like notificiations :/) So this PlayerPrefences object can have a method, enQueueTrackId: and another called getQueue: your one VC can call enQueueTrackId: to add a song to it, then the tableVC when it appears, can call getQueue and load the tracks from e.g. CoreData using the IDs.

Comment: Ran out of text. So you start centralising all this player specific data into an object, leaving you free to extend and change VCs in the future. If you add new VCs that require certain things from the preferences, you extend your PlayerPreferences object and add an interface or protocol to it. Then the VC can use that. Always remember to keep objects to their responsibilities. You can then test your code easierly, extend and reuse code etc.

Comment: Thanks. I have run into another little problem, now that I'm doing it this way. When I dismiss the pageViewController. my last page does not stay in memory, so I always start with the first page upon reloading and presenting my pageViewController. Should I also keep a pointer to the last pageContentViewController in my singleton? Argh

Comment: You could use NSUserDefaults for the index, save it in viewWillDissappear and load it viewWillAppear before scrolling to that index. Dont turn the singleton into a dumping ground :)

Comment: Problem with this now is that the index will stick around even after the app is closed.

Comment: You can remove it in the app notifications if you like. Register for app terminate notification on your class and remove the object from UserDefaults

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it, which feels like a hack but works, is to access the viewcontroller's view's frame.

```
CGRect dontCareRect = myNewViewController.view.frame
```

That forces the vc's view to load.